# Example that is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I did some linear algebra exercise and did the following: Give an example of a nonempty subset $U$ of the xy-plane with the property that $U$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication but $U$ is not a subspace.

I believe the set $U=\{(x,y): xy=0\}$ should provide such an example. Are there any better examples? More visual ones?

Comment: Your example is perfect. Visually, it represents the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes (which is a union of two lines through the origin that are not collinear). It fails to be a subspace because it isn't closed with respect to vector addition.

Comment: @Adriano Sorry, I don't see how it is the union of the x and the y axis? Could you say a bit more?

Comment: @newb: The points for which $xy=0$ are exactly the ones that are either on the $x$ axis or on the $y$ axis (or both).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh yes, right. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite (or countable!) set of lines through the origin, at least two of which are not collinear.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is perfect. Visually, it represents the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes (which is a union of two lines through the origin that are not collinear). It fails to be a subspace because it isn't closed with respect to vector addition.

To see your example is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes, observe that:
$$ \begin{align*}
U &= \{(x,y): xy=0\} \\
&= \{(x,y): x=0 \text{ or } y=0\} \\
&= \{(x,y): x=0\} \cup \{(x,y):y=0\} \\
&= (y\text{-axis}) \cup (x\text{-axis})
\end{align*}$$